# How to move fast in street view of google earth/google map?

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps, google-earth

Clicking just let you move 1 step forward. How to move multi-steps?

I understand that images are generally not recommended, but in this situation, I think it is reasonable for me to upload one for reference

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USNIo.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can usually hover your mouse over different anchor points on the picture and jump as far as you can see.

[image: Screenshot of Street View's anchor system]

It's not obvious because they are pretty transparent but you can have a look in the picture. The cursor is this kind of arrow while the anchor is a cross on the ground. Moving the cursor will trigger the closest anchor and when the right anchor is selected you can click to move to its point of view.

Comment: Thanks, but would like to clarify that this anchor is only available in google map street view but not google earth street view